# How to widen .li right edge after left:-20px;?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list, bootstrap-4

I have a nested list like this...

[image]

What you're seeing is a recursive ul/li package...

```
<div class="family d-block">
   <span class="pb-2"> <small class="text-muted">Family:</small><br>
   </span> 
   <span class="small">
      <span><img
         src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wpp.com" width="12"
         class="mr-2"><a
         href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/">WPP</a></span>
      <ul>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/24-7-realmedia/"
            title="View all products in 24/7 realmedia">24/7
            realmedia</a>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=akqa.com" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/akqa/" title="View
            all products in akqa">akqa</a></li>
         <li>
            <img
               src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=groupm.com"
               width="12" class="mr-2"><a
               href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/" title="View
               all products in GroupM">GroupM</a>
            <ul>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=finecast.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/finecast/"
                  title="View all products in Finecast">Finecast</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/group-m-entertainment/"
                  title="View all products in group m entertainment">group m
                  entertainment</a>
               </li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=maxusbelgium.be"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/maxus/"
                  title="View all products in Maxus">Maxus</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=mec.ca" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mec/"
                  title="View all products in MEC">MEC</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wavemakerglobal.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mec-global/"
                  title="View all products in mec global">mec global</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=mediacom.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mediacom/"
                  title="View all products in MediaCom">MediaCom</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=mindshareworld.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mindshare/"
                  title="View all products in Mindshare">Mindshare</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/modi-media/"
                  title="View all products in modi media">modi media</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=realmedia.group"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/real-media-group/"
                  title="View all products in real media group">real media
                  group</a>
               </li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=xaxis.com" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/xaxis/"
                  title="View all products in Xaxis">Xaxis</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=jwt.co.uk" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/jwt/" title="View
            all products in JWT">JWT</a></li>
         <li>
            <img
               src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=kantar.com"
               width="12" class="mr-2"><a
               href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/kantar/" title="View
               all products in kantar">kantar</a>
            <ul>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=kantarmedia.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/kantar/kantar-media/"
                  title="View all products in kantar media">kantar
                  media</a>
               </li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/kantar/tns-media-intelligence/"
                  title="View all products in tns media intelligence">tns media
                  intelligence</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=millwardbrown.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/millward-brown/"
            title="View all products in Millward Brown">Millward
            Brown</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <img
               src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=ogilvy.com"
               width="12" class="mr-2"><a
               href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/ogilvy/" title="View
               all products in ogilvy">ogilvy</a>
            <ul>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=ogilvyentertainment.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/ogilvy/ogilvy-entertainment/"
                  title="View all products in ogilvy entertainment">ogilvy
                  entertainment</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=possible.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/possible/"
            title="View all products in possible">possible</a></li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=vml.com" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/vml/" title="View
            all products in VML">VML</a></li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wavemakerglobal.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/wavemaker/"
            title="View all products in Wavemaker">Wavemaker</a></li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wunderman.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/wunderman/"
            title="View all products in
            Wunderman">Wunderman</a></li>
      </ul>
   </span>
</div>
```

... With i) bullets removed and ii) each list item set farther to the left (because I felt there was too much space with the existing indentation)...

```
.family ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.family ul li {
  position:relative;
  left:-20px;
}
```

The problem with setting list items farther left, however, seems to be that the horizontal space for each list item's text does not now stretch to meet the right-most edge. This is causing premature wrapping of text.

If I turn on some colouring, you can see the difference with `left: -20px;` on and off...

[image]

So, how can I restore the ability of list item text to stretch to the right-most edge (red)?

I don't mind changing the underlying method with which I have forced list items to start rom a farther left edge, as long as I can maintain the effect.

And I can make use of any Bootstrap 4/flex classes if they support this.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech My CSS was included in the question. The two described rules are the only addition to Bootstrap 4, which is also included.

Comment: `ul` usually come with a default `padding-left`, maybe you just want to overwrite that instead …

Comment: Hi @RobertAndrews trying applying some css to the <ul> of  ```padding-left: 30px;```. Usually comes with 40px as standard, so to make it smaller just apply a smaller value.

Comment: These all seem to work as answers. First, better to apply to `ul`, not `li`. Second, on `ul`, use negative `margin-left: -20px;` or positive `padding-left: 20px`. It was wrong of me to use `position`. Padding intervention feels more right. These successfully push the usable space to the right edge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm understanding your question correctly you'll just want to change up the strategy like below (added some visual boundary indicators). 
Would also sprinkle in some minimal ARIA attributes for the folks who appreciate them;

```
<nav role="navigation">
   <ul role="tree">
      <li role="treeitem">Parent</li>
      <li role="treeitem">Parent
         <ul role="tree">
            <li role="treeitem">Child</li>
            <li role="treeitem">Child</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem">Parent</li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Either way, hopefully this helps. Cheers!

```css
.family ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: red 1px dotted;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.family ul li {
  border: green 1px dotted;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="family d-block">
   <span class="pb-2"> <small class="text-muted">Family:</small><br>
   </span> 
   <span class="small">
      <span><img
         src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wpp.com" width="12"
         class="mr-2"><a
         href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/">WPP</a></span>
      <ul>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/24-7-realmedia/"
            title="View all products in 24/7 realmedia">24/7
            realmedia</a>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=akqa.com" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/akqa/" title="View
            all products in akqa">akqa</a></li>
         <li>
            <img
               src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=groupm.com"
               width="12" class="mr-2"><a
               href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/" title="View
               all products in GroupM">GroupM</a>
            <ul>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=finecast.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/finecast/"
                  title="View all products in Finecast">Finecast</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/group-m-entertainment/"
                  title="View all products in group m entertainment">group m
                  entertainment</a>
               </li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=maxusbelgium.be"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/maxus/"
                  title="View all products in Maxus">Maxus</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=mec.ca" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mec/"
                  title="View all products in MEC">MEC</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wavemakerglobal.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mec-global/"
                  title="View all products in mec global">mec global</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=mediacom.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mediacom/"
                  title="View all products in MediaCom">MediaCom</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=mindshareworld.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/mindshare/"
                  title="View all products in Mindshare">Mindshare</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/modi-media/"
                  title="View all products in modi media">modi media</a></li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=realmedia.group"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/real-media-group/"
                  title="View all products in real media group">real media
                  group</a>
               </li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=xaxis.com" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/groupm/xaxis/"
                  title="View all products in Xaxis">Xaxis</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=jwt.co.uk" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/jwt/" title="View
            all products in JWT">JWT</a></li>
         <li>
            <img
               src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=kantar.com"
               width="12" class="mr-2"><a
               href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/kantar/" title="View
               all products in kantar">kantar</a>
            <ul>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=kantarmedia.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/kantar/kantar-media/"
                  title="View all products in kantar media">kantar
                  media</a>
               </li>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=null" width="12"
                  class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/kantar/tns-media-intelligence/"
                  title="View all products in tns media intelligence">tns media
                  intelligence</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=millwardbrown.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/millward-brown/"
            title="View all products in Millward Brown">Millward
            Brown</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <img
               src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=ogilvy.com"
               width="12" class="mr-2"><a
               href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/ogilvy/" title="View
               all products in ogilvy">ogilvy</a>
            <ul>
               <li><img
                  src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=ogilvyentertainment.com"
                  width="12" class="mr-2"><a
                  href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/ogilvy/ogilvy-entertainment/"
                  title="View all products in ogilvy entertainment">ogilvy
                  entertainment</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=possible.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/possible/"
            title="View all products in possible">possible</a></li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=vml.com" width="12"
            class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/vml/" title="View
            all products in VML">VML</a></li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wavemakerglobal.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/wavemaker/"
            title="View all products in Wavemaker">Wavemaker</a></li>
         <li><img
            src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=wunderman.com"
            width="12" class="mr-2"><a
            href="http://www.example.com/organisation/wpp/wunderman/"
            title="View all products in
            Wunderman">Wunderman</a></li>
      </ul>
   </span>
</div>
```